# i3: enabling fullscreen by default

Tags: i3

With i3, is it possible to have all new windows open in fullscreen by default?
As far as I have been able to find, this is only possible for specified programmes.

Comment: What I think is you should try something like `[class="<>"] fullscreen enable`. The only thing I have no idea how to specify in <> something that would match any window. The wildcard is the thing to try I guess.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the following configuration setting:

```
for_window [class=".*"] fullscreen enable
```

The `for_window [CRITERIA] COMMAND` setting runs `COMMAND` for each new window matching `CRITERIA`. *i3* uses PCRE (Perl-compatible regular expressions) for pattern matching, so the pattern `.*` matches any number of arbitrary characters. Meaning it matches any possible class name, even empty ones.

Comment: The criterion `all` matches all windows (`for_window [all] fullscreen enable`, see User's Guide, part 6 - List of Commands). Major drawback of enabling fullscreen for all windows is the fact that small dialog windows become stretched to full screen too. Maybe playing with `for_window ... floating enable` will help.